# mail vs sendmail

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, sendmail

I am using the Email class in Codeigniter, and in the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) I see that there are 3 protocols that can be used: mail, sendmail and smtp.

What is the dfiference between mail and sendmail? Is it true that using mail protocol will have a higher chance of having the domain marked as spam?

Comment: Email classes most of the time adds all recommended and needed header attributes, or formats content. While mail is very basic plain, you may miss some required headers.

Comment: @alickus Does this mean that sendmail is the recommended protocol to use since it has more headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using *nix, chances are mail() and sendmail() are identical. mail() will still use sendmail, but it passes any arguments you have defined in your php.ini.

The bigger difference is between SMTP and sendmail. If you are doing a lot of mass emailing you want to use SMTP because sendmail opens a new connection for each email which adds quite a bit of overhead.